# Converting to 8-bit image causes white spots where black was. Why is this?

Tags: image, image-processing, numpy, filter, signal-processing

Img is a dtype=float64 numpy data type. When I run this code:

```
Img2 = np.array(Img, np.uint8)
```

the background of my images turns white. How can I avoid this and still get an 8-bit image?

[image]

[image]

Edit:

Sure, I can give more info. The single image is compiled from a stack of 400 images. They are each coming from an .avi video file, and each image is converted into a NumPy array like this:

```
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

A more complicated operation is performed on this whole stack, but does not involve creating new images. It's simply performing calculations on each 1D array to yield a single pixel.

The interpolation is most likely linear (the default in plotting images with matplotlib. The images were saved as .PNGs.

Comment: You say that the image has the data type `float64`, but what is the actual image format? Is it a 16bit tiff or a 8 bit jp(e)g or what kind of image format has the original input? It is obvious that you lose contrast when reducing the depth of your image! Furthermore, how do you plot? Is there some interpolation used? Please share more code (loading `Img`, plotting `Img2`) to see what's going on!

Comment: I added an edit with more info.

Comment: I don't see the background turning white. The first image is the input and the second the 8-bit coverted?

Comment: In the bottom image (the original), the background is solid black. In the top, parts of the background randomly become white. Just wondering why that is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably see overflow. If you cast `257` to `np.uint8`, you will get `1`. According to a google search, `avi` files contain images with a color depth of 15 - 24 bit. When you cast this depth to `np.uint8`, you will see white regions getting darkened and (if a normalization takes place somewhere) also dark regions getting white (`-5` -> `251`). For the regions that become bright, you could check whether you have negative pixel values in the original image `Img`.

The [Docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html) say that sometimes you have to do some scaling to get a proper cast, and to rather use higher depth whenever possible to avoid artefacts.

The solution seems to be either working at higher depth, i.e. casting to `np.uint16` or `np.uint32`, or to scale the pixel values before reducing the depth, i.e. with `Img2` already being a numpy matrix

```
# make sure that values are between 0 and 255, i.e. within 8bit range
Img2 *= 255/Img2.max() 
# cast to 8bit
Img2 = np.array(Img, np.uint8)
```

Comment: Perfect! Definitely overlooked this.